# UK short term study visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

How do I show sufficiently strong family, social and economic ties to satisfy the entry clearance officer that I intend to leave the UK after my 8 weeks short course for my Visa application?

What documents do I need to provide as a student who is unemployed?

Comment: You need to think outside the box a little. How far are you through your studies? Nearing the end of a degree course would likely be a stronger reason to return than if you’re in your first year. How well does the short course you want to attend fit with your studies in your home country? What is your family situation - do you have family in UK? Do you belong to / officiate in any clubs/societies, local religious activities? What savings do you have? Can you meet the eligibility criteria https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/eligibility

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold.